# Is there any Android API to get CPU and battery status?

Tags: java, android, measurement, energy

I'm working in my thesis, and I need to explore the google Android API to find a way to get every possible information about the CPU and Battery (like CPU temperature, % of usage, battery level, energy consumption, ...).

The idea is measuring, in 2 or more different execution times, the energy consumed by an Android APP, and get details on what was used by the APP to spend that energy.

Does anyone know any API from Android to measure this kind of things?

Comment: Good luck. Background services etc allow multiple apps to run all the time, you'll have to figure out how much an app contributes to the current consumption :) Apps can also cause load in other processes so it's not as easy as checking cpu load per app process.

Comment: yes, I know that :)
The idea is make an average measure of the energy consumption.
For example, executing the APP 10 or 20 times and get the values I want, and then get an average value from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting battery level, you can register an Intent for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED. For more information refer to the [Android Battery API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html). If you just want to get the battery temperature, you can get it using the API itself. I think Android does not have an API for CPU temperature.

However, you can read the temperature from /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
This is the way to get temperature on linux based systems and since Android is Unix based, I think you should be able to do it. I haven't tried it myself though

Comment: Many thanks! I think it would be really useful.
I haven't thought about using Unix files to get the information I need, but it might be a good solution.
Do you know any other tips to get information about the CPU from Unix files?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Monitoring the Battery Level and Charging State](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) guide. Concerning CPU, you should be able to collect some data from [Systrace](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html).

Comment: Yes, I already saw the Monitoring guide ([link](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html)), and for the battery I may use it.
But for the CPU I was thinking about using an API too, and Systrace is more a tool :/ The goal is transforming the entire source code of an APP and make it save the values I want, and for that a tool is more complicated to use...
But I thanks for the help :)